# Ошибка при переносе базы данных mysql в phpmyadmin с локального сервера на хостинг

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Я экспортирую базу данных сайта на modx с локально сервера на хостинг, при импорте базы в phpmyadmin на хостинге вылезает ошибка

[image: ошибка]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь перенести БД сделанную на сервере с более свежей версией MySQL на сервер с версией ниже.

Чтобы исправить эту ошибку, Вам нужно заменить строки в вашем дампе с

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

на

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```